# Connecting to database with Android

Tags: java, android, json

This code is not connecting me with my database. Neither in the register nor in login case. There is no syntax error. It is executed to the progress bar, after that the app goes to the previous activity and the progress bar dismisses.

I tested my database query with the HTML form which worked correctly but here with Android it is not working.

```
public class Backgroundworker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    String register_url= "http://10.0.2.2/aps.dp/register.php";
    String login_url= "http://10.0.2.2/aps.dp/login.php";
    Context cnx;
    Activity activity;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public Backgroundworker(Context cnx){

        this.cnx =cnx;
        activity = (Activity)cnx;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(cnx);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to server....");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];


        if (type.equals("register")) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String name = params[1];
                String email = params[2];
                String password = params[3];
                String age = params[4];
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("age", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(age, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) ;
                {

                    stringBuilder.append(line + "/n");

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Thread.sleep(5000);


                return bufferedReader.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        else if (type.equals("login"))
        {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String email = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) ;
                {

                    stringBuilder.append(line + "/n");

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Thread.sleep(5000);


                return bufferedReader.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        try {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String code = JO.getString("code");
            String message = JO.getString("message");
            if (code.equals("reg.true")){
                showDialog("Registration Success", message,code);
            }
                else if (code.equals("reg_false")){


                showDialog("Registration Failed", message,code);


            }
            else if (code.equals("login_ture"))
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("message",message);
                activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
            else if (code.equals("login_false"))
            {
                showDialog("Login Error......", message,code);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    public void showDialog (String title, String message,String code ){

        builder.setTitle(title);
        if ((code.equals("reg_true"))||(code.equals("reg_false")))
        {

            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    activity.finish();

                }
            });


        }

            else if (code.equals("login_false"))
        {
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    EditText email, password;
                    email = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.logEmail);
                    password = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.logpass);

                    email.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });


        }

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();


    }
}
```

Comment: So, only the progress bar appears and you go back to the previous activity? Does the progress bar gets dismissed (even instantaneously)?

Comment: yes the progress bar dismiss